# unionfs for cifs mounts

Tags: cifs, unionfs

I want to merge some cifs mounts together.

There are

```
/extDrives/cifs_001
/extDrives/cifs_002
/extDrives/cifs_003
/extDrives/cifs_common
```

cifs_common should show all content of cifs_00*
Writes to cifs_common should be placed on one of the 00* with enough free space.

I tried

```
- aufs --> writes to cifs_common creates "Device busy" errors 
- unionfs-fuse --> writes are only done on the first mount
```

Any idea how to merge the cifs mounts?

-- Rüdiger